# Add object to array in an MVC model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

If I have a strongly typed view with a model that has an array of another object, is it possible to have a strongly typed partial view that adds that other object to the model?

For example, if I had a view typed `HandSurvey`, which has an array of `CurrentGlove`, could I have a partial view in the hand survey form strongly typed to `CurrentGlove` that when the user hits the submit button, it doesn't return a new view, but adds a `CurrentGlove` object to the `HandSurvey` model's array? How would I go about that? Sorry if that didn't make sense, I am having a lot of trouble getting a grasp on the mvc structure.

These are the models:

```
public class HandSurveyModel
{
    public HandSurveyModel() { }

    [DisplayName("Location Number:")]
    public string LocationNumber { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Location Name:")]
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public List<HandSurveyRisk> Risks { get; set; }
    public List<CurrentGlove> CurrentGloves { get; set; }
}

public class CurrentGlove
{
    public CurrentGlove() { }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string UOM { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

this is the code in the view, typed to `HandSurveyModel`:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Hand Protection Survey</legend>
        <% using (Html.BeginForm("HandSurvey", "Resources"))
           { %>
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(x => Model.LocationNumber)%>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.LocationNumber) %></div>
        <div>
            <%= Html.LabelFor(x => Model.LocationName)%>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.LocationName) %></div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Risk Assessment</legend>
            <fieldset style="float: left; margin: 10px">
                <legend>Chemical</legend>
                <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Risks.Count; i++)
                   {%>
                <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Risks[i].IsChecked)%>
                <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Risks[i].Text)%>
                <br />
                <%} %>
            </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" value="OK" />
            <% } %>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Current Gloves</legend>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Resources/CurrentGlove.ascx", new CurrentGlove()); %>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
</asp:Content>
```

this is the code in the partial view, typed to `CurrentGlove`:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("CurrentGlove", "Resources")) { %>
    <%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
    <p><input type="submit" value="OK" id="btnSearch"/></p>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Please post your code so far. Also I feel like you asked this already a couple days ago?

Comment: @Yuck, code added. You are correct sort of, I actually asked about how to update a datagrid based on this form. But now realized that I don't even know how to get to that point...

Answer (score 1):

Try checking [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) guide. I think it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more of a MVC3 guy so this might be a guess.

Take the form out of your partial view for `CurrentGlove`.

Move the form in your first view to encompass the partial view for `CurrentGlove.ascx`

And when calling the partial view, do it like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Resources/CurrentGlove.ascx", Model.CurrentGloves); %>
```

Now when the form posts, it will pass in all the form data into the action at the same time.

Comment: I need to allow the user to add multiple `CurrentGlove`'s to the model on the Hand Survey and once they're done, submit the Hand Survey as a whole. So how would they be able to enter info for a single `CurrentGlove`, then hit a button that adds it to the array in the `HandSurvey` model?